# How to draw two boxes with different sizes in the same row with custom shape in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I achieve two boxes in one row while one of them has a triangle and lay over the other box, grey box over white box on flutter as in the image below? I am new to flutter and am clueless on how to get started on this, I tried with my code but I was able to do two boxes with the same size, if I added width to container it doesn't work.

this is what I want to do simillar

[image]

my work

[image]

```
    child:Column(children: [
      Row(children: [
        Flexible(
          child:Container(
            height: 50,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 2,
              vertical: 2,
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0XFFDDDDDD),
              borderRadius:BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5),
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(children: [
              Icon( Icons.email,color: Colors.black45, size: 20),
              SizedBox(width: 2),
              Expanded(child: Text('Email', style: robotoRegular)),

            ]),
          ),),

        Flexible(
          child:   Container(
            height: 50,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 2,
              vertical: 2,
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius:BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(5),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(5),
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(children: [

              SizedBox(width: 2),
              Expanded(child: Text('example@mysite.com', style: robotoRegular)),

            ]),
          ),),
      ]),
    ])
```

Comment: You will need to use a `ClipPath` with a `CustomClipper` on your `Container` to define a custom shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using `CustomPainter`:

```
class NotchPainter extends CustomPainter {
  late double notchSize;
  NotchPainter({
    this.notchSize = 5,
  });
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var path = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, size.height / 2 - notchSize)
      ..relativeLineTo(notchSize, notchSize)
      ..relativeLineTo(-notchSize, notchSize)
      ..close();
    var paint = Paint()..color = Color(0XFFDDDDDD);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

To paint notch over the second widget you need to wrap it with `CustomPaint` like this:

```
 Column(children: [
   Row(children: [
     Flexible(
       child: Container(
         height: 50,
         padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
           horizontal: 2,
           vertical: 2,
         ),
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
           color: Color(0XFFDDDDDD),
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
             topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
             bottomLeft: Radius.circular(5),
           ),
         ),
         child: Row(
           children: [
             Icon(Icons.email, color: Colors.black45, size: 20),
             SizedBox(width: 2),
             Expanded(child: Text('Email')),
           ],
         ),
       ),
     ),
     Flexible(
       child: CustomPaint(
         foregroundPainter: NotchPainter(notchSize: 8),
         child: Container(
           height: 50,
           padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
             horizontal: 2,
             vertical: 2,
           ),
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
             color: Colors.white,
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
               topRight: Radius.circular(5),
               bottomRight: Radius.circular(5),
             ),
           ),
           child: Row(children: [
             SizedBox(width: 8),
             Expanded(child: Text('example@mysite.com')),
           ]),
         ),
       ),
     ),
   ]),
 ])
```

In NotchPainter you can pass the desired notch size(default is 5).

Result:

[image: Result Image]